# How to install SQLite backend for GnuCash on Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: 18.04, sqlite, gnucash

I was using GnuCash without problem on Ubuntu 16.04. Now I am not able to open GnuCash file after switching to 18.04. It give this message:

> No suitable backend was found for...

If I remember correctly, I was using SQLite backend. However now I cannot find way to install SQLite backend for GnuCash, though I already installed sqlite3 package.

Is it possible to install SQLite backend for GnuCash in default Ubuntu repository?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found it myself.

Just need to install libdbd-sqlite3 package.

```
sudo apt-get install libdbd-sqlite3
```

I got this info from https://wiki.gnucash.org/wiki/index.php?title=Building&oldid=14056 (Original link was  https://wiki.gnucash.org/wiki/Building#Ubuntu_14.04_LTS_.28Trusty_Tahr.29 but it got updated and does not contain that help now)

Comment: This link is a bit dated, but still comes up. Unfortunately, it no longer mentions database backends. While the suggested remedy still works, the only place I could find this referenced for Ubuntu was here: https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy/gnucash . The wiki (https://wiki.gnucash.org/wiki/Ubuntu) *should* mention it -- the wiki for Redhat sure does -- but any mention thereof is unfortunately absent.

Comment: @fbicknel I improved that link to point to the old version.